# yii2 gives error 404 but the file exists?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

so i am building a youtube clone with php and yii2 right now but when i created my own Controller and try accesing it i get a 404 Error.
My controller (backend/controllers):

```
<?php

namespace backend\controllers;
use yii\web\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller {
    public function actionIndex() {
        return $this->render('index');
    }

}
```

my index.php (backend/views/hello):

```
<?php
 echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the full and exact error message, along with your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase where can i find the full error message?

Comment: runtime folder look at it

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco    in backend/runtime the only file is a .gitignore file set to ignore .gitignore

and this is the only log i found in frontend/runtime/logs
https://gist.github.com/SusgUY446/e96d10bc39667a516defb727e44b4d1e

Comment: From the poor code you've posted i see you are trying to render a view called index.php but your view is hello.php (backend/views/hello).